# Reallocing 2nd dimension

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am allocing space for array using

```
int **pml=0;
int **tmp=(int **)realloc(pml, 100 * sizeof(*pml));
pml=tmp;
```

and try to alloc 2d dimension

```
  for ( i = 0; i < 100;i++){
       pml[i]=(int *)malloc(10 * sizeof ( int ));
       pml[i][0]=2; // for storing index
       pml[i][1]=10; // for realoc
  }
```

What i am trying to achieve is following = user inputs 2 numbers , 1st is for index and second is value so if i input 3 and 5 , the array should look like

```
array{{2,10},{2,10},{2,10},{2,10,5}}
```

i am doing it with this vode
X=1st number e.g index Y=value;

```
  if(pml[X][0]==pml[X][1]){
                pml[X][1]+=10;
                pml[X]=(int *)realloc(pml[X], pml[X][1] * sizeof ( int );}
                pml[X][pml[X][0]=X;
                pml[X][pml[0]]+=1;

           }
```

But with bigger input , throws segmentation fault Valgrind throw this message

```
==4270== Invalid read of size 8
==4270==    at 0x400873: main (in ../a.out)
==4270==  Address 0x5445f40 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2,400,000 alloc'd
==4270==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4270==    by 0x4C2CF1F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4270==    by 0x400778: main (in /../a.out)
==4270== 
==4270== Invalid read of size 4
==4270==    at 0x400876: main (in /../a.out)
==4270==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4270== 
==4270== 
==4270== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4270==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==4270==    at 0x400876: main (in /h../a.out)
==4270==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4270==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4270==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4270==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4270==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4270== 
==4270== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4270==     in use at exit: 14,400,000 bytes in 300,001 blocks
==4270==   total heap usage: 300,001 allocs, 0 frees, 14,400,000 bytes allocated
==4270== 
==4270== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4270==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4270==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4270==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4270==    still reachable: 14,400,000 bytes in 300,001 blocks
==4270==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4270== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4270== 
==4270== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4270== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Which means some realloc went wrong , but i do not see any mistake - where did i wrong reallocated field?

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! Note: There is no 2D array in your code. You have a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays.

Comment: That looks more like a use-case for and array of `struct`s. In general, if you watn to store heterogenous data, use a `struct`. Possibly with a _flexible array member_.

Comment: `pml[X][pml[0]]+=1;` That doesn't look right. `pml[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: I am relativly new to c ... i wanted to make array filled with structs but was told it is not possible in c

Comment: Johnnz Mopp - fixed it to pml[X][0]+=1 , still segmantation

Comment: The user only inputs 2 numbers, one for index and one for value, but you are modelling a 2D array, so shouldn't the user input 3 numbers, two for the indices and one for the value?

Comment: @Abdir: Whoever told you is wrong. Of course you can have an array of `struct` (here maybe better pointers to `struct`). Maybe you read a good C book, it should be explained there very well.

Comment: could you recommend good source for this? I was looking for it quite a while and found nothing

Comment: Concerning book recommendation, review "book" in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a dynamic array or stack. You can greatly simplify things by using a struct:

```
struct Stack {
    int capacity;
    int index;
    int *data;
};
```

Then, you want 100 of these (not sure why)...

```
struct Stack *pml = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct Stack));
```

Then initialize

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pml[i].capacity = 10;
    pml[i].index = 0;
    pml[i].data = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Then you can set the data with a function

```
void Push(struct Stack *stack, int value) {
    // Check for reallocation
    if (stack->index == stack->capacity) {
        stack->capacity *= 2;  //Assumes capacity >= 1
        stack->data = realloc(stack->data, sizeof(int) * stack->capacity);
    }
    // Set the data
    stack->data[stack->index++] = value;
}
```

And call it like

```
Push(&pml[n], 234);   // Where n < 100, is the nth stack in the array
```

And, of course you need to `free()` everything at some point.

(Note, you should add error checking.)

Comment: Suggest `stack->data = realloc(stack->data, sizeof *(stack->data) * stack->capacity);` so structure field `data` type can be changed without needing to search/update code for `malloc()/realloc()`.

Comment: when i want to print some value from array , it always prints 0 , why? i tried it with this code using printf("%d",pml[X].data[pml[X].index]);

Comment: I set it up as a stack. Do you want a stack or an array? I threw together an example of a stack: https://ideone.com/mcbP5P.